# Como usar o super() de forma correta?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, tkinter

Sou iniciante e estou tentando aprender o framework tkinter, porem estou com uma duvida agora que é a utilização do super(), sei que o super é uma forma de herdar a classe "main" para "subclasses" , porém no exemplo do tkinter é usado super() logo na classe "main", segue o código exemplo.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()


    def create_widgets(self):
        self.hi_there = tk.Button(self)
        self.hi_there["text"] = "Hello World\n(click me)"
        self.hi_there["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.hi_there.pack(side="top")

        self.quit = tk.Button(self, text="QUIT", fg="red",
                                command=self.master.destroy)
        self.quit.pack(side="bottom")

    def say_hi(self):
        print("hi there, everyone!")

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Por que usar super() nesse caso?

Comment: Acho que `Application` nesse caso usa como super classe `tk.Frame`. Então o uso da palavra `super` dentro da classe é sempre uma referência à `tk.Frame`. Quando uma classe não está herdando nada de outra, o statement de declaração da classe é apenas `class Nome:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa sua dúvida não tem a ver com tkinter, tem a ver com orientação a objetos. Vamos lá.

## A teoria é importante

```py
class A():
    def metodo1(self):
        print('metodo1 da classe A')

class B(A):
    def metodo2(self):
        print('metodo2 da classe B')
```

No código acima, a classe `B` foi declarada como subclasse da `A`. Isso significa que todos os métodos e propriedades declarados na `A` também fazem parte da `B`.

Se você criar um objeto da classe `B` pode chamar o `metodo1`.

```py
obj_b = B()
obj_b.metodo1()
```

Ele vai printar "metodo1 da classe A", mesmo você tendo instanciado um objeto da classe `B`. É exatamente pra isso que serve o sistema de herança de classes.

Agora imagine que você queira declarar um método na classe `B` cujo nome já existe na classe `A`. O que vai acontecer?

```py
class A():
    def metodo1(self):
        print('metodo1 da classe A')

class B(A):
    def metodo2(self):
        print('metodo2 da classe B')

    def metodo1(self):
        print('metodo1 da classe B')

obj_b = B()
obj_b.metodo1()
```

Ele vai printar "metodo1 da classe B". Quando existem dois métodos com o mesmo nome, o Python escolhe o que foi declarado na própria classe.

Caso você precise acessar um método da superclasse cujo nome já tenha sido utilizado na subclasse, você deve usar o `super()`.

```py
class A():
    def metodo1(self):
        print('metodo1 da classe A')

class B(A):
    def metodo2(self):
        print('metodo2 da classe B')

    def metodo1(self):
        print('metodo1 da classe B')

    def metodo3(self):
        super().metodo1()

obj_b = B()
obj_b.metodo3()
```

Ele vai printar "metodo1 da classe A", pois o `método3` usa o `super()` pra chamar diretamente a superclasse.

## Recapitulando

Você declarou a classe `Application` como subclasse da `tk.Frame`.

```py
class Application(tk.Frame):
```

E a classe `Application` já declara um método chamado `__init__` (que é o seu construtor).

```py
    def __init__(self, master=None)
```

Por isso você precisa do `super()` para chamar o método `__init__` da classe `tk.Frame`.

```py
super().__init__(master)
```

Senão o construtor chamaria a si mesmo e, consequentemente, entraria em loop infinito.

Recomendo estudar orientação a objetos *antes* de usar frameworks. As coisas farão mais sentido.